# Bootstrap 4 to add hover box shadow issue

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I used [bootstrap 4](https://getbootstrap.com/) , i tried to added list hover to some box shadow option, but its appear to all of text and images , you can see the issue on it following code snippets ,

anyone know how to add this correctly

this is my **css code**

```
.my-lst :hover{
/*  transform: scale(1.04);*/
 cursor: pointer;
box-shadow: 0 2px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16), 0 2px 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);

}
```

Thanks

```css
.my-lst :hover{
/*  transform: scale(1.04);*/
 cursor: pointer;
box-shadow: 0 2px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16), 0 2px 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);

}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>



<main role="main" class="container">


  <div class="my-3 p-3 bg-white my-lst  rounded shadow-sm">
  
    <div class="media text-muted border-bottom  pt-3">
      <svg class="bd-placeholder-img mr-2 rounded" width="32" height="32" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" focusable="false" role="img" aria-label="Placeholder: 32x32"><title>Placeholder</title><rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#007bff"/><text x="50%" y="50%" fill="#007bff" dy=".3em">32x32</text></svg>
      <div class="media-body pb-3 mb-0 small lh-125 border-gray">
        <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center w-100">
          <strong class="text-gray-dark">Full Name</strong>
          <a href="#">Follow</a>
        </div>
        <span class="d-block">@username</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="media text-muted my-lst  border-bottom pt-3">
      <svg class="bd-placeholder-img mr-2 rounded" width="32" height="32" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" focusable="false" role="img" aria-label="Placeholder: 32x32"><title>Placeholder</title><rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#007bff"/><text x="50%" y="50%" fill="#007bff" dy=".3em">32x32</text></svg>
      <div class="media-body pb-3 mb-0 small lh-125  border-gray">
        <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center w-100">
          <strong class="text-gray-dark">Full Name</strong>
          <a href="#">Follow</a>
        </div>
        <span class="d-block">@username</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="media text-muted my-lst pt-3 border-bottom">
      <svg class="bd-placeholder-img mr-2 rounded" width="32" height="32" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" focusable="false" role="img" aria-label="Placeholder: 32x32"><title>Placeholder</title><rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#007bff"/><text x="50%" y="50%" fill="#007bff" dy=".3em">32x32</text></svg>
      <div class="media-body pb-3 mb-0 small lh-125  border-gray">
        <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center w-100">
          <strong class="text-gray-dark">Full Name</strong>
          <a href="#">Follow</a>
        </div>
        <span class="d-block">@username</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    
  </div>
</main>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The selector `.my-lst :hover` targets to the `:hover` pseudo-class of all *descendants* of `.my-lst`. Not only does it target the `<div>` with the class `media-body`, but also the `<strong>` and `<a>` children of it.

To only target the box, you're looking for the *direct* descendant selector (*[child combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_combinator)*) `>`:

```css
.my-lst > :hover {
  /*  transform: scale(1.04);*/
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16), 0 2px 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>



<main role="main" class="container">


  <div class="my-3 p-3 bg-white my-lst  rounded shadow-sm">

    <div class="media text-muted border-bottom  pt-3">
      <svg class="bd-placeholder-img mr-2 rounded" width="32" height="32" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" focusable="false" role="img" aria-label="Placeholder: 32x32"><title>Placeholder</title><rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#007bff"/><text x="50%" y="50%" fill="#007bff" dy=".3em">32x32</text></svg>
      <div class="media-body pb-3 mb-0 small lh-125 border-gray">
        <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center w-100">
          <strong class="text-gray-dark">Full Name</strong>
          <a href="#">Follow</a>
        </div>
        <span class="d-block">@username</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="media text-muted my-lst  border-bottom pt-3">
      <svg class="bd-placeholder-img mr-2 rounded" width="32" height="32" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" focusable="false" role="img" aria-label="Placeholder: 32x32"><title>Placeholder</title><rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#007bff"/><text x="50%" y="50%" fill="#007bff" dy=".3em">32x32</text></svg>
      <div class="media-body pb-3 mb-0 small lh-125  border-gray">
        <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center w-100">
          <strong class="text-gray-dark">Full Name</strong>
          <a href="#">Follow</a>
        </div>
        <span class="d-block">@username</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="media text-muted my-lst pt-3 border-bottom">
      <svg class="bd-placeholder-img mr-2 rounded" width="32" height="32" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" focusable="false" role="img" aria-label="Placeholder: 32x32"><title>Placeholder</title><rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#007bff"/><text x="50%" y="50%" fill="#007bff" dy=".3em">32x32</text></svg>
      <div class="media-body pb-3 mb-0 small lh-125  border-gray">
        <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center w-100">
          <strong class="text-gray-dark">Full Name</strong>
          <a href="#">Follow</a>
        </div>
        <span class="d-block">@username</span>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</main>
```

Answer (score 3):

please remove space after `lst`, 
<del>.my-lst :hover</del>

Code will be this type, 
`.my-lst:hover`

Answer (score 1):

Check it's working only where you add class 'my-lst'.

```css
.my-lst:hover{
/*  transform: scale(1.04);*/
 cursor: pointer;
box-shadow: 0 2px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16), 0 2px 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);

}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>



<main role="main" class="container">


  <div class="my-3 p-3 bg-white my-lst  rounded shadow-sm">
  
    <div class="media text-muted border-bottom  pt-3">
      <svg class="bd-placeholder-img mr-2 rounded" width="32" height="32" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" focusable="false" role="img" aria-label="Placeholder: 32x32"><title>Placeholder</title><rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#007bff"/><text x="50%" y="50%" fill="#007bff" dy=".3em">32x32</text></svg>
      <div class="media-body pb-3 mb-0 small lh-125 border-gray">
        <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center w-100">
          <strong class="text-gray-dark">Full Name</strong>
          <a href="#">Follow</a>
        </div>
        <span class="d-block">@username</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="media text-muted my-lst  border-bottom pt-3">
      <svg class="bd-placeholder-img mr-2 rounded" width="32" height="32" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" focusable="false" role="img" aria-label="Placeholder: 32x32"><title>Placeholder</title><rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#007bff"/><text x="50%" y="50%" fill="#007bff" dy=".3em">32x32</text></svg>
      <div class="media-body pb-3 mb-0 small lh-125  border-gray">
        <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center w-100">
          <strong class="text-gray-dark">Full Name</strong>
          <a href="#">Follow</a>
        </div>
        <span class="d-block">@username</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="media text-muted my-lst pt-3 border-bottom">
      <svg class="bd-placeholder-img mr-2 rounded" width="32" height="32" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" focusable="false" role="img" aria-label="Placeholder: 32x32"><title>Placeholder</title><rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#007bff"/><text x="50%" y="50%" fill="#007bff" dy=".3em">32x32</text></svg>
      <div class="media-body pb-3 mb-0 small lh-125  border-gray">
        <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center w-100">
          <strong class="text-gray-dark">Full Name</strong>
          <a href="#">Follow</a>
        </div>
        <span class="d-block">@username</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    
  </div>
</main>
```

Answer (score 1):

The class my-lst shows up multiple times in your HTML code, meaning all of your CSS will apply to all instances of my-lst. Add a label to the container you want the hover effect and call the label in your CSS instead of the class.

Comment: Thanks your solution, but your description better to put comment section

Answer (score 1):

check this in snippet

```css
.my-lst:hover{
/*  transform: scale(1.04);*/
 cursor: pointer;
box-shadow: 0 2px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16), 0 2px 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);

}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>



<main role="main" class="container">


  <div class="my-3 p-3 bg-white my-lst  rounded shadow-sm">
  
    <div class="media text-muted my-lst  border-bottom  pt-3">
      <svg class="bd-placeholder-img mr-2 rounded" width="32" height="32" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" focusable="false" role="img" aria-label="Placeholder: 32x32"><title>Placeholder</title><rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#007bff"/><text x="50%" y="50%" fill="#007bff" dy=".3em">32x32</text></svg>
      <div class="media-body pb-3 mb-0 small lh-125 border-gray">
        <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center w-100">
          <strong class="text-gray-dark">Full Name</strong>
          <a href="#">Follow</a>
        </div>
        <span class="d-block">@username</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="media text-muted my-lst  border-bottom pt-3">
      <svg class="bd-placeholder-img mr-2 rounded" width="32" height="32" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" focusable="false" role="img" aria-label="Placeholder: 32x32"><title>Placeholder</title><rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#007bff"/><text x="50%" y="50%" fill="#007bff" dy=".3em">32x32</text></svg>
      <div class="media-body pb-3 mb-0 small lh-125  border-gray">
        <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center w-100">
          <strong class="text-gray-dark">Full Name</strong>
          <a href="#">Follow</a>
        </div>
        <span class="d-block">@username</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="media text-muted my-lst pt-3 border-bottom">
      <svg class="bd-placeholder-img mr-2 rounded" width="32" height="32" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" focusable="false" role="img" aria-label="Placeholder: 32x32"><title>Placeholder</title><rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#007bff"/><text x="50%" y="50%" fill="#007bff" dy=".3em">32x32</text></svg>
      <div class="media-body pb-3 mb-0 small lh-125  border-gray">
        <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center w-100">
          <strong class="text-gray-dark">Full Name</strong>
          <a href="#">Follow</a>
        </div>
        <span class="d-block">@username</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    
  </div>
</main>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the space between your class name and the pseudu-class.

<strike>`.my-lst :hover`</strike> to `.my-lst:hover`

```css
.my-lst:hover {
  /*  transform: scale(1.04);*/
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16), 0 2px 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>



<main role="main" class="container">


  <div class="my-3 p-3 bg-white my-lst  rounded shadow-sm">

    <div class="media text-muted border-bottom  pt-3">
      <svg class="bd-placeholder-img mr-2 rounded" width="32" height="32" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" focusable="false" role="img" aria-label="Placeholder: 32x32"><title>Placeholder</title><rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#007bff"/><text x="50%" y="50%" fill="#007bff" dy=".3em">32x32</text></svg>
      <div class="media-body pb-3 mb-0 small lh-125 border-gray">
        <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center w-100">
          <strong class="text-gray-dark">Full Name</strong>
          <a href="#">Follow</a>
        </div>
        <span class="d-block">@username</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="media text-muted my-lst  border-bottom pt-3">
      <svg class="bd-placeholder-img mr-2 rounded" width="32" height="32" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" focusable="false" role="img" aria-label="Placeholder: 32x32"><title>Placeholder</title><rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#007bff"/><text x="50%" y="50%" fill="#007bff" dy=".3em">32x32</text></svg>
      <div class="media-body pb-3 mb-0 small lh-125  border-gray">
        <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center w-100">
          <strong class="text-gray-dark">Full Name</strong>
          <a href="#">Follow</a>
        </div>
        <span class="d-block">@username</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="media text-muted my-lst pt-3 border-bottom">
      <svg class="bd-placeholder-img mr-2 rounded" width="32" height="32" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" focusable="false" role="img" aria-label="Placeholder: 32x32"><title>Placeholder</title><rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#007bff"/><text x="50%" y="50%" fill="#007bff" dy=".3em">32x32</text></svg>
      <div class="media-body pb-3 mb-0 small lh-125  border-gray">
        <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center w-100">
          <strong class="text-gray-dark">Full Name</strong>
          <a href="#">Follow</a>
        </div>
        <span class="d-block">@username</span>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</main>
```